# Django QuerySet sorting not iterating in order

Tags: django, sorting, iteration, sql-order-by, django-queryset

I am trying to sort a table(model) based on a column(of type floating point) in descending order.

```
studs = student.objects.all().order_by('-marks')
```

After that I tried to iterate over the resulting queryset so that I can get the students in their descending order of marks.

```
for stud in studs:
```

When I checked the the value of stud in the first iteration its not showing the student details with highest marks.

Anyone please help me whats the issue with the code

Student model is given below.

```
class student(models.Model):
   reg_no = models.CharField(max_length=10,primary_key=True)
   roll_no = models.CharField(max_length=4)
   name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
   dept_code = models.ForeignKey('department')
   marks = models.FloatField()
```

It's working fine in template.. But I have to do this in my views.py file, and there its not working as my expectaion.

Comment: Please edit your question to show us the model for `student`.

Comment: I have provide the details

Answer (score 1):

You can either do it in the model meta by adding an `order_with_respect_to`

```
class Meta:
        order_with_respect_to = '-marks'
```

Or through the template by using a template filter

```
{{ stud|dictsort:"-marks" }}
```